# Store queue of function pointers, invoke them upon popping

Tags: c++

I have a function and I calculate the function arguments on the fly.

I'd like to store a pointer to the function and the arguments so to push them on a queue and execute "later".

I have performance requirements, so I'd like to avoid `std::function`, lambdas, any of the other C++11 code which encapsulates complexity and just stick with raw pointers and primitives.

I have this so far:

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct Pool
{
    void push(T& t)
    {
        m_queue.push(t);
    }

    void pop()
    {
        T t = m_queue.front();
        m_queue.pop();
        t();              // Pop and invoke the function here
    }

    std::queue<T> m_queue;
};

void func1(int p, double q)
{
    std::cout << p << " " << q << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    using F1 = void(*)(int, double);

    F1 f1 = &func1;

    Pool<F1> pool_1;
    pool_1.push(f1(4, 5.6));
    pool_1.pop();
}
```

but I'm struggling with the compiler error:

```
error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'void (*)(int, double)' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'void'
    pool_1.push(f1(4, 5.6));
```

Comment: Do you want to bind the arguments when you push, but still only call the function when you pop ?

Comment: `std::queue<T>::pop` doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: You say you aren’t using `std::function` for performance reasons (which you’re almost certainly wrong about), but the extra functionality of `std::function` over function pointers is exactly what you’re trying to use here.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Correct. I wish to defer invocation until later after I pop.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai My code is probably wrong then. I have one function signature per Pool, hence it's templated. I know the function argument values when I push but I only wish to execute the function "later". In this example later can be after we pop from the queue.

Comment: where do you want to store the arguments? Where do the arguments come from?

Comment: @Sneftel actually `std::function` does more than that. `std::function` can be used to store a callable that has the arguments bound, but the main feature of `std::funciton` is the type erasure

Comment: I think the question is almost like "how to do std::bind without using std::bind and std::function". You can always do `auto lam = [f1]() { f1(4, 5.6); }` , but for the container you need to have some common type anyway.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The argument values are calculated on the fly and only known shortly before I push. You are correct I wish to "group" them together, to execute shortly afterwards (in this example, when we pop).

Comment: would it be an option to pass the arguments to `pop` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Unfortunately I don't think so. Think of this as a thread pool. My main thread calculates the arguments, pushes the arguments + pointer on a queue and then a consumer threads pops and executes the function with the arguments.

Comment: you should [edit] the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store the arguments together with the function pointer you can do it like this:

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

// trait to get type of tuple of arguments from function pointer
template <typename T> struct args_as_tuple;

template <typename R,typename...Args>
struct args_as_tuple<R(*)(Args...)> { using type = std::tuple<Args...>; };

template <typename T> using args_as_tuple_t = typename args_as_tuple<T>::type;


template<class T>
struct Pool {
    struct pointer_and_args {
        T ptr;
        args_as_tuple_t<T> args;
    };
    void push(const pointer_and_args& p) {
        m_queue.push(p);
    }

    void pop() {
        // call first then pop to avoid unecessary copy
        pointer_and_args& t = m_queue.front();
        std::apply(t.ptr,t.args);
        m_queue.pop();
    }

    std::queue<pointer_and_args> m_queue;
};

void func1(int p, double q) {
    std::cout << p << " " << q << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    using F1 = void(*)(int, double);
    Pool<F1> pool_1;
    pool_1.push({func1,{4, 5.6}});
    pool_1.pop();
}
```

Reference arguments will need extra consideration, but from what you describe you need only values.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding references, I will need them but the lifetime of my objects is guaranteed across our period of interest, so that should be fine.

Comment: @intrigued_66 of course you need to ensure that the references are valid. I was refering to storing them in the queue. Also you say one thread is pushing the other is popping, which will also need extra measures to be taken when the arguments are references

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but so long as the underlying memory address doesn't change the references (or pointers) will always be valid? I have a larger object I will pass in by reference. However, it's stored in an array, so the address never changes.

Comment: @intrigued_66 say you have threads A and B. With values it is sufficent to synchronize `push` in A and `pop` in B. With refercenes any access to the object has to be synchronized.